# Why the second command wasn't started in the BAT-file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I run in the `cmd.exe` at first

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

and then

```
start MSBuild.exe /t:BatchRebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /noautoresponse "C:\Users\developer\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AutoCAD_Net_Extension1\AutoCAD_Net_Extension1\AutoCAD_Net_Extension1.csproj"
```

then both commands was executed successfully.

But when I write them into the `BAT`-file - the second command wasn't started:

```
:: This script builds your project for all target AutoCAD versions, are pointed
:: in the "BuildFor" property of your csproj-file.
:: WARNING If you will rename your csproj-file later, then don't forget to do 
:: the same in this file (look last parameter of the msbuild command below).

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" 

start MSBuild.exe /t:BatchRebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /noautoresponse "C:\Users\developer\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AutoCAD_Net_Extension1\AutoCAD_Net_Extension1\AutoCAD_Net_Extension1.csproj"
```

Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working variant (it is necessary to add the `call` for other BAT-file executing):

```
:: This script builds your project for all target AutoCAD versions, are pointed
:: in the "BuildFor" property of your csproj-file.
:: WARNING If you will rename your csproj-file later, then don't forget to do 
:: the same in this file (look last parameter of the msbuild command below).

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" 

MSBuild.exe /t:BatchRebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /noautoresponse "C:\Users\developer\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AutoCAD_Net_Extension1\AutoCAD_Net_Extension1\AutoCAD_Net_Extension1.csproj"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in quotes for Start MUST be windowtitle. Put a blank one in.

```
Start "" rest of command line
```

Comment: I added now, but it doesn't help me still. :(((

Comment: MSBuild is not in AppPaths so there's no way to find it. Specify full paths. And there's no need for the Start command at all.

Comment: `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /t:winexe "%userprofile%\desktop\VBS2Exe.vb"`

Comment: Therefore I run the `VsDevCmd.bat` before, so all works fine. Look my answer.